# Android Management API and KIOSK Mode App with NFC Tag - not work

Tags: android-management-api

We made an android app with nfc support and want to activate the kiosk mode over Android Management API. It worked all well. But NFC is not working anymore.
We know that Management API uses Android Device Policy App for DCP, so it is not possible to set our app as device owner and set the taskLockPackage for com.android.nfc

How can we enable NFC for the KIOSK app?

We logged the output and it says that nfc is not allowed. So com.android.nfc is not available in kiosk mode.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

Previously, there was an issue where NFC functionality wasn't available for Android devices in Kiosk mode. This problem has been resolved starting from Android 13 and above. If you're facing difficulties with NFC in Kiosk mode, make sure your devices are updated to Android 13 or a later version to benefit from the fix. Updating your devices to the latest Android version often resolves such issues and seamlessly enables NFC for your KIOSK app.